# How to transfer children component to component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render in my `Text` component another component using: `{this.props.child}`

What should I choose and why?

```js
<Route path={'/test'} render={() => <Test children={Test1} />} />
```

or

```js
<Route path={'/test'} render={() => <Test><Test1 /></Test>} />
```

Comment: You should use the second way with `this.props.children`, it will be assigned automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `children` prop should always be passed like:

```
<Test><Test1 /></Test>
```

You may want other JSX passed as a prop sometimes though, like when setting a smaller bit of content somewhere, like a `title`. You can then even use both forms:

```
<Test title={<h1>Big title</h1>}>
  <ChildrenComponent />
</Test>
```

But, for consistency, the `children` prop should always be the component's actual children.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the second way:

`<Route path={'/test'} render={() => <Test><Test1 /></Test>} />`

The `render` prop provides the ability for inline rendering and passing extra props to the element. This prop expects a function that returns a React element when the current location matches the route’s path.